# three figures to the the top in a 2-column page plus captions

Tags: floats, multicolumn, includegraphics

Hi I am having troubles aligning 3 figures to the top of a 2-column page. I want to take as much space as possible (within the margins). I also need to insert long captions below the figures but they don't stay in a limited space. 
I'm using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`
How do I use the `figure` and `\includegrapghics` properly?

This is what I am trying to do but I don't want subfigures:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fig1.eps}\caption{Here goes a very looooooooooooong caption.}\label{fig:vishay}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fig2.eps}\caption{Here goes a very looooooooooooong caption.}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{subfigure}
% Same thing for fig3...
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: please show us what you try so far! the best in form of small but complete document (with dummy text) . is you figures span both columns?

Comment: The maximum width for figure is \columnwidth, and the maximum width for figure* is \textwidth.  The maximum height for one or more figures in one column is \topfraction\textheight.  Note: you can place multiple captions in one figure*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEEEtran` is not compatible with `subcaption`, use enfironment `subfloat` from the package `subfig` instead:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\textwidth}
\subfloat[Here goes a very looooooooooooong caption,
          \label{fig:subfig-a}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[Here goes a very looooooooooooong caption,
          \label{fig:subfig-b}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[Here goes a very looooooooooooong caption,
          \label{fig:subfig-c}]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}

\caption{common caption for sub figures \dots}
\label{fig:common}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**
in the case, that you like to have three images in line, than you they encapsulate in `minipage`s or in `table` environment. in later case the mwe is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{Here goes a very very very very very long caption}
\label{fig:subfig-a}
    &
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{Here goes a very  very very very very long caption}
\label{fig:subfig-b}
    &
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\caption{Here goes a very  very very very very long caption}
\label{fig:subfig-c}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to have three separate captions, like Fig.1, Fig.2 and Fig.3, without the common caption?

Comment: @raff5184, yes, it is possible. see edited answer.

Comment: @raff5184, any news? if answer fulfill your expectation it will be nice if you accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of the answer) :-)